# i got [vue/no-parsing-error] Parsing error: Unexpected token {

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Chats.php

```
<ChatsComponent :user="{{ Auth::user()}}" />
```

in ChatsComponent.php

```
<template>
 <div  class="container font-sans antialiased h-screen flex">
 <span class="font-bold">{{user.name}}</span>
 </div>
</template>



<script>
export default {
props:['user'],
}
</script
```

**I dont know why i get this error iam using laravel8.x with innertia + vue**

Comment: What is the purpose of ```:user="{{Auth::user()}}"```? This is prop syntax and div is not a component.

If you accept "user" as props, why do you use Laravel syntax in Javascript, BTW, it's not possible as far as I know. So your problem is there but the code doesn't make your intention clear.

Comment: Now looks good, but you are still trying to use a Laravel code in Js. It's not possible. Laravel codes are executed in the server while Js in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution is that i can't use Laravel syntax in  javascript as they mentioned in the comment  so i get user detail via controller and assign to props

is it a good practice? i don't know.

Comment: I recommend you to use **Vuex**, So at login, you can save that user to **Store** and retrieve easily anywhere in your **Vue** code.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `!!` inside the brackets like :

```
<ChatsComponent :user="{{!! Auth::user() !!}}" />
```

Comment: still deos not work, ive no idea couse im new to laravel and vue

Comment: try it out without binding sign `user="{{ Auth::user()}}"`

Comment: your file should be named `Chats.blade.php`